# Can I close the ServerSocket after accepting a client socket and establishing a connection?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

The question is general, although my simple program is in Java. It concerns TCP/IP connections.

What I need is the server socket to close as soon as possible after establishing a client connection. I need maximum one client at a time, and I don't want anybody else to be able to connect.

I noticed that if I close the server socket, I can still use the client socket but nobody is listening for further connections. Actually this is perfectly fine for me, but I'm not sure if there aren't some hidden dangers in that approach.

What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I close the ServerSocket after accepting a client socket and establishing a connection?

Yes. The listening socket and the accepted socket are completely independent.

However it might make more sense to just execute all the client handling code in the accept loop and then go back to the accept, instead of starting a new thread per client as is customary. That way, further clients can connect, but they just won't get any service until the first client finishes. So you don't have to code retries into the clients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's comforting to know that. I really need to close the socket though. How did you know the answer - is this something well known and/or documented, or it's just observation (as was mine also)?

Comment: Absence of documentation to the contrary, some knowledge of the internals, understanding of the protocol, and 25 years' experience.